# "Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it." while running php artisan migrate command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and want to modify a string field to a text field like this:

```
//the old field that i want to modify in migration file
$table->string('description')->nullable();

//and the new text field
$table->text('description')->change();
```

I get the following error:

> Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this solution may be this will work for you,

```
public function __construct()
{
    DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('json', 'text');
}
```

For further reading about this issue check [Issue #15772](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15772) at laravel repo

Comment: pleasure  bro :)

Comment: You saved my day Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you found this question at google, but your case is Symfony, but not Laravel - this is an answer.

Had same issue: `Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.` at Symfony/Sylius.

The reason - I had `serverVersion=5.5` rather than `serverVersion=5.7` at my app's `.env` file, when `doctrine 2.6+` was installed by composer.

So right `DATABASE_URL` will be: `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1/database_%kernel.environment%?serverVersion=5.7`

Comment: this is the real answer! json type is supported from MySQL 5.7 on!

Comment: @NDM Can you explain what you mean? There is no "serverVersion" in Laravel's .env file and there doesn't seem to be such an option in the database.php config either.

Answer (score 5):

If using Symfony, you have to make sure your dbal config is pointing at the correct server version:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: "%database_host%"
    port: "%database_port%"
    dbname: "%database_name%"
    user: "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset: utf8mb4
    server_version: 5.7
    default_table_options:
      charset: utf8mb4
      collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      engine: InnoDB
```

Comment: or if your server version < 5.7 you can add following config:
`
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types:
            json: text
`

Answer (score 3):

The right fix for this problem is to add a server version on config/database.php under the MySQL section.

```
'server_version' => "5.7"
```

because if you don't, Doctrine will use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform which supports all versions of MySQL since MySQL 5.0 which does not support JSON fields, and by adding the server_version Doctrine will load MySQL57Platform that have support for JSON instead of MySqlPlatform.

example of database MySQL config for Laravel 7:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'server_version' => "5.7",
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```