# Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Running into the above error while attempting to run `doctrine:schema:update` in Symfony.

The error is happening in AbstractPlatform (part of \lib\Doctrine\Platforms\AbstractPlatform)

I'm checking and JSON is definitely registered in \lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.php

```
abstract class Type
{
    const TARRAY = 'array';
    const SIMPLE_ARRAY = 'simple_array';
    const JSON_ARRAY = 'json_array';
    const JSON = 'json';
...
}
```

Version of MySQL is 5.7.26 so that should be ok (json is a type here)

I'm just trying to figure out a workaround.

I tried adding

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            enum: json
```

to doctrine.yaml

but that has had no effect.   Does anyone know a workaround?   I have no idea where the json file is being called...

---

Edit: I've come across a similar situation here but the answer is for Laravel:
["Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it." while running php artisan migrate command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256476/unknown-database-type-json-requested-doctrine-dbal-platforms-mysql57platform-m)

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this for Symfony?

Comment: Have you declared your DB server version on `doctrine.yml`?

Comment: Yes.  It's declared as '5.7'

Comment: make sure your DBAL config is pointing at the correct server version: server_version: 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, here's a hackish workaround I came across here https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6540

In AbstractPlatform, I just modified the error check to convert json files into strings.    Not ideal, but it got past this error.

```
 public function getDoctrineTypeMapping($dbType)
{
    if ($this->doctrineTypeMapping === null) {
        $this->initializeAllDoctrineTypeMappings();
    }

    $dbType = strtolower($dbType);

//inserted hack here

    if($dbType == 'json') {
        $dbType = 'string';
    }
//

    if (!isset($this->doctrineTypeMapping[$dbType])) {
        throw new \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException("Unknown database type ".$dbType." requested, " . get_class($this) . " may not support it.");
    }

    return $this->doctrineTypeMapping[$dbType];
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it, because you change dependencies files. Please use this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654174/doctrine-makemigration-unknown-database-type

Answer (score 2):

make sure your dbal config is pointing at the correct server version:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: "%database_host%"
    port: "%database_port%"
    dbname: "%database_name%"
    user: "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset: utf8mb4
    server_version: 5.7
    default_table_options:
      charset: utf8mb4
      collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      engine: InnoDB
```

Comment: This is the real solution!

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 enum: Doctrine\DBAL\Types\JsonType
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was a `composer update` from a minor version to an other so it was a bug in the Doctrine DBAL.